# Is there already implemented algorithm in Networkx to return paths lengths along with paths?

Tags: python, networkx, shortest-path

I am using shortest_simple_paths() that is implemented in Networkx to find k-shortest/best paths between two nodes.
[shortest simple paths](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.shortest_simple_paths.html#networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.shortest_simple_paths)

However, I also need the algorithm to return the path length of the returned path. I will need the path length based on already configured 'weights' and not based on hop counts. I know this is a simple problem and can be implemented very easily, but I couldn't find one that is already implemented and effective.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do this.  So I think you'll probably want to implement it yourself.  By the way - I don't think I'd seen a question about the k-shortest paths till a couple months ago, and now I've seen about 5.  I'm curious why the sudden interest - is there a reason you're after this?

Comment: Thank you @Joel! It is just for my research. There is nothing in particular.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved by including `len(path)` in the for loop from the [Examples section of `shortest_simple_paths`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.shortest_simple_paths.html#networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.shortest_simple_paths).

```
G = nx.cycle_graph(7)
paths = list(nx.shortest_simple_paths(G, 0, 3))
print(paths)
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 6, 5, 4, 3]]
```

Modify the edges from the linked example so the shorter path by "hop counts" has a higher cumulative `weight` than the longer path.

```
for u,v in G.edges():
    if (all(i < 4 for i in [u,v])):
        G[u][v]['weight'] = 0.75
    else:
        G[u][v]['weight'] = 0.25
```

Copy the `k_shortest_paths` function, again from the link.

```
from itertools import islice
def k_shortest_paths(G, source, target, k, weight=None):
     return list(islice(nx.shortest_simple_paths(G, source, target, weight=weight), k))
```

Compare the output of `k_shortest_paths` when `weight='weight'` and `weight=None`:

```
for path in k_shortest_paths(G, 0, 3, 2, weight='weight'):
    print(path, len(path))
([0, 6, 5, 4, 3], 5)
([0, 1, 2, 3], 4)

for path in k_shortest_paths(G, 0, 3, 2, weight=None):
    print(path, len(path))
([0, 1, 2, 3], 4)
([0, 6, 5, 4, 3], 5)
```

Comment: @Mohamed Ibrahim Please mark answers which resolve your issue by checking the box left to it.